# 128 error while installing local python dependencies with requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, gitlab

I tried to install local python dependencies with requirements.txt file

My requirements.txt

> -e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project

I got such error

> WARNING: Discarding git+ssh://****@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project. Command errored out with exit status 128:
> git clone -q 'ssh://****@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_grouo/my_project.git' 'c:\polygon\projects\test_project\venv\src\my-project'. ERROR: Could not fine a version that satisfies the requirement my-project (unavailable). ERORR: No matching distribution found for my-project (unavailable)

But then I install local dependencies with this command all dependencies install without any errors

> pip install -U git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master

How to fix this problem with installation with requirements.txt?
I follow the instructions from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

Answer (score 1):

Check first if modifying your `requirements.txt` to include the `git@` user in the URL would work.

You say `pip install -U git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/...` works.
Therefore, the `requirements.txt` should also include:

```
 git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/
           ^^^
```

The [OP tibhar940](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633450/tibhar940) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366085/128-error-while-installing-local-python-dependencies-with-requirements-txt/66366522#comment117333517_66366522):

> That was my fault - I tried
>
> ```
> -e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com:my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> -e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that in question description. I use this line in requirements.txt `-e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project` UPD: and I fixed an error description.

Comment: @tibhar940 Apparently, from your own question, you have `git+ssh://****@git.ext.my_gitlab.com` instead of `git+ssh://git@git.ext.my_gitlab.com`

Comment: I have `-e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project` and I fixed that in question.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, I have `-e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project` and I fixed that in question, and in error message in question.

Comment: @tibhar940 Does GitLab runs with the same user as the one you have when you executed (successfully) the `pip install` command?

Comment: that was my fault - I tried `-e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com:my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project` instead of `-e git+ssh://git@ext.my_gitlab.com/my_group/my_project.git@master#egg=my_project`

Comment: @tibhar940 OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.